# Apache Not Following Symlinks (403) : Creating Symlinks Within Vagrant : Windows Host, Ubuntu Guest

Tags: apache, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, symlink

The main problem for me is that apache is not following my symlinks and is giving me 403 errors.

- I am using a Windows host and Ubuntu ~14.04 Guest
- I have made the symlinks within Windows host, and are within the vagrant/virtualbox shared folders.
- Within my virtualhosts, I have apache set to follow symlinks.
- I have also set chmod -R /var/www to user www-data
- Within my Vagrantfile, I have a line as follows:

  ```
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/", "1"]
  end
  ```
- Ubuntu was telling me I cannot create symlinks because of protocol error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

Windows Symlinks do NOT work in Linux as far as I can tell.
Creating a symlink using ln -s was giving me "protocol error" when sshed into my box with vagrant.

I had to start a command line in windows with admin properties and ssh in, and only then was I able to create a linux symlink. Once I created the symlinks in linux, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced the same issue where I was receiving 'protocol error' whilst attempting to create a symlink (`ln -s`) between two synced vagrant folders (NFS).

As these folders technically reside in Windows `ln -s` will return an error; you'll also receive an error if you attempt to `cd` to a directory (in your vagrant box) after performing `mklink` between Windows directories in command-prompt.

As a result, I attempted to try creating a Windows symlink that points to the target directory using unix-style directory format, as follows:

`mklink /D "D:\My New Symlink\" "/home/vagrant/my_target_folder"`

Let me know if it doesn't work for you and I'll check my vagrant config file for any potential settings that allow this.